# Description of the boundary of a ball

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Solving an optimization problem in multiple variables, I had to examine a function
$$
f(x,y,z)=x^2+2yz
$$
defined on a ball
$$
\{ (x,y,z)\enspace|\enspace x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1 \}.
$$
The boundary is then described by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. According to my textbook, one can search for maxima on the boundary by rewriting $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ as $x^2=1-y^2-z^2$, then substituting this into $f$ to obtain
$$
f(x,y,z)=1-y^2-z^2+2yz,\quad y^2+z^2\leq1
$$
Now what I don't understand is, how come we need to specify that $y^2+z^2\leq1$? The unit sphere is described by $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ with no need to specify any restrictions on $y$ or $z$, but once we rewrite this as $x^2=1-y^2-z^2$ and plug it into the function, suddenly it becomes necessary to specify that $y^2+z^2\leq1$. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write $$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$

The set of solutions implicitly has the restriction that $y^2+z^2\le1$ because if this condition is violated there are no solutions in $\mathbb R$.

$$y^2+z^2\gt1$$

$$x^2+y^2+z^2\gt1+x^2$$

$$1\gt1+x^2\implies x^2\lt0\implies x\in \phi$$

Comment: Right, but if it's implicit from the beginning, why do I have to write it explicitly later? Shouldn't it still be implicit?

Comment: @Andreas In $f(x,y,z)$ there is no "$\color{red}{=}$". It is simply an expression. You need to point out, that the *inputs* into $f$ come from an "$\color{red}{=}$"(which is constrained by some inequalities)

Comment: To make myself clearer, $f(x,y,z)$ is defined for all $x,y,z$, but you are only using that definition on the points *on* the sphere. $f(100,100,100)$ has a very well defined value, but that value is never obtained for the points on the sphere.

Comment: $f$, clearly doesn't have a global maxima, but there is a maximum value for points *within* or *on* the sphere.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. I assumed that, because we inserted $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ into the function, the function would implicitly contain the equality $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. I see now that it doesn't.

Comment: @Andreas yes you're right. It doesn't contain the equality. You need to explicitly enforce that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Because $0 \leq x^2 = 1-y^2-z^2$.

Comment: But if $y^2+z^2\leq1$ is already implied by $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, why do I have to write it explicitly?

Comment: Because you "forget" the $x$ variable.